# Automatic inference of static methods for derived wrapper classes

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'd like the static methods (which act as builders) defined on a base class to automatically infer a derived class and the wrapped type. I have been able to infer one or the other, but not both. A simplified example and a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GEJKcBGASwgDsAeAFQD44BvAWACg5XEy0YoBXQ6ACjBQiANxQxgcAPog0ALjiUA2gF0AlPQC%20zZmzidxRBHABmUCAFsAglCgoAngEZyWOKAmkAJphj2wwCBNsXHxCElIAGkVqfhgACyJ5bCjZBWV1BQBJUgNSBGBKP2AXWkYWPTYoYBhuKFI4UmAAdzh4xP5ZDXQ4bNz8wv8SgG5dNm0mUdYDYmMzSxs7ewAmFzcQD29gvAJiMipqKJpYhKTGlo6k9I0AXlosFMvVNQVXMorK6tr6s9aTi7URuVWONxsxQJBYIhUBg4ABRdbALzATw4bZhPY0NYbTCo0K7CiYuigpgAehJcAA4hAUEgFChuDBLIYEDSkPY4ERSCZgFA4N14RtkbiduFyKRuBYAEY86jMBAceAERxwa5whFIlEhEVkAB0c2stgcjn4SkcUSWUQAzOpAfKcoqEEsVWrBZq0fi9eYDYsliazXALXBrQDmEA) to fiddle with:

```
export class Collection<T> {
    constructor(private _xs: T[]) {}

    static fromArray1<C extends typeof Collection, T>(this: C, xs: T[]): InstanceType<C> {
        return new this(xs) as InstanceType<C>;
    }

    static fromArray2<C extends Collection<T>, T>(this: new (xs: T[]) => C, xs: T[]): C {
        return new this(xs);
    }
}

export class ExtendedCollection<T> extends Collection<T> {}

// Goal: automatically infer as ExtendedCollection<number>
const ec1 = ExtendedCollection.fromArray1([1, 2, 3]);
const ec2 = ExtendedCollection.fromArray2([1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible in TypeScript, but there are some workarounds.

Comment: @caTS I am all in for these workarounds!

Comment: TS doesn't have higher kinded types. You can emulate/simulate them but this needs boilerplate on the order of one extra line per subclass, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mq3nRw). If you're just trying to give polymorphic types to one method per class, it's not worth it, and it would be better to just give up and manually annotate the method returns in subclasses [like this](https://tsplay.dev/WoAgpN). Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz if you reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! I think both approaches are useful and insightful (so for completeness you may include both in the answer). In my scenario, I'd go for your first approach, I have quite some static methods. I noticed while writing `fromArray1` that I was in need of HKT, but I was hopping in `fromArray2` for TS to somehow infer all the way down to `=> C`. But, as you said in some old comment, TS has some limitations with this kind of generics inference.

Comment: So should I write up the first approach as an answer?

Comment: On second thought, the first approach needs to know in advance the derived classes, right, but that's a generic library that will be extended as the programmer wants, so I'll have to go for the second approach.

Comment: For the second approach the programmer would have to extend the subclasses in "the right" way, and the programmer can extend the interface in the first approach also, so I don't see what it has to do with consumer of the library. It's just different manual boilerplate that the programmer has to do, but it's still busywork.  I'm still not sure what you want me to do. I'm happy to write up an answer explaining why this doesn't just work (no HKTs) and describing the two approaches, and then you can implement either or neither in your real use case. Sound okay?

Comment: @jcalz Sounds okay!

Comment: Okay I'll write it up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major impediment to your goal is the absence of direct support for *higher kinded types* in TypeScript, of the sort requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  Right now you can build generic types like `type Gen<T extends Foo> = ...` where the type parameter `T` represents some specific type, but you can't abstract over that to make a higher generic type like `type Higher<F<~> extends Gen<~>> = ...` where the type parameter `F` represents some generic type which itself takes a type argument like `Gen`.

If you could, then maybe you would be able to write

```
// NOT VALID TS, DON'T TRY THIS:
static fromArray<C<~> extends Collection<~>, T>(
  this: new (...args: any) => C<any>, 
  xs: T[]
): C<T>;
```

and "apply" the generic type parameter `C` to the type `T` to produce `C<T>`. But this is not directly supported, so we have to work around it.

---

The issue, microsoft/TypeScript#1213, mentions several flavors of workaround.  All of them currently require some boilerplate code that needs to be maintained.  For example, if you are willing to [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) a property into an interface for every defined subclass of `Collection<T>`, you can define an "apply"-like type function:

```
export class Collection<T> {
    constructor(private _xs: T[]) { }
    static fromArray<C extends typeof Collection, T>(this: C, xs: T[]): Apply<C, T> {
        return new this(xs) as any;
    }
    x = 0

}

interface HKT<T> { Collection: Collection<T> }

type Apply<C extends new (...args: any) => any, T> =
    { [K in keyof HKT<any>]:
        HKT<any>[K] extends InstanceType<C> ?
        InstanceType<C> extends HKT<any>[K] ?
        HKT<T>[K] : never : never }[keyof HKT<any>]
```

From the above, you could figure out that `Apply<typeof Collection, number>` will produce `Collection<number>`.  Then for subclasses, you merge in another property:

```
export class ExtendedCollection<T> extends Collection<T> {
    y = 1
}
// manually merge in this
interface HKT<T> { ExtendedCollection: ExtendedCollection<T> }
```

And now, `Apply<typeof ExtendedCollection, string>` will produce `ExtendedCollection<number>`.  So your example will work as desired:

```
const ec1 = ExtendedCollection.fromArray([1, 2, 3]);
// const ec1: ExtendedCollection<number>
ec1.y
```

---

Without trying to simulate higher kinded types, the only other workaround I can think of is to just give up on abstracting "apply `C` to `T`" over all `C`, and instead just manually narrow each subclass so that its methods have hardcoded references to themselves:

```
export class Collection<T> {
    constructor(private _xs: T[]) { }
    static fromArray<T>(xs: T[]): Collection<T> {
        return new this(xs) as any;
    }
    x = 0
}
```

So that's the base class, and then subclasses will just mark their method types  appropriately without actually modifying them:

```
export class ExtendedCollection<T> extends Collection<T> {
    static fromArray: <T>(xs: T[]) => ExtendedCollection<T>;
    y = 1;
}
```

And again, the example works as desired:

```
const ec1 = ExtendedCollection.fromArray([1, 2, 3]);
// const ec1: ExtendedCollection<number>
ec1.y
```

---

Neither method is perfect, obviously.  There may be other workarounds that fit your needs more closely, but until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#1213 is implemented, I don't think there are any completely pain-free ways of doing it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9AVKDCCCByByAKgAgCIHlXIBIEkBlUAEwFMBjAGwEMAnM1amgZxdWgHsqrKAXAJacAdgB5kAPlQBvUKnmoADnQEA3Gn0YB9AB4sAXDgDaAXQDcchRREs+dAK4U+nOgApdB4yYCUFkAtRbDQEKVAAzOk4AW1g6OhoAT1FoUQA-KTIdTWESdi4efiExdIAaHAlXPgALAU9hMgB3VFcAOjb6AHNPGmEE71QAXikUnoSJMr1DZFNvQxTJPwBfUAgwUGEaKLIWRRoKRkIBKPtaTVwAaTRZEEt5TMUXPiZaNg5uXici8SlrgIDrYS2BxOFyuZRqDTaSZefrSVDLfx-eRBQShCLRWLxJLQVCZbK5VB8BKKMicMJvAqfERlSSVGqeaATTzTHyGWCKRRUbE0n63JEKBh8ex0YSoepNaq1Vx6fqsVCjPz8+F8gI6QaoAAMoD5CICYDAqCiPXsNB4CUNZDoHUYAlFkpYfNtmjoYT2jAuyG+MgpH0EIjm70KIi9CL590ez1Y7AAolkyDkyCR8r6vpJcXGcnlA1SxGnfvzzQNUABGHV8-WG42mrkWq02u30x3CZ2u-aoD1euGx-GJ5NB4SGbvx8hJ7N+3NSUOI+REkmodmc7Hp-HscXNNotTrdXr9Iby3o8wYqhRwoznVC21AAazICTJ7cuolGEhM+mPSI7z7PJmXw-Y+EBPgen2ZBiTIZIpAAfnfP4AKCYQQLAiDf0zB9PS-c4f2g6clTQ75v1QQx6lUS1CLFMgSLoeEjBvO9yU-XoX21G4cIBWxcQoYt1SHBNR0pccWnRGI4kSVwjGLMoACYygAZh8RUFArNinkoYtBwzEc+xzURhHsKIACNLQkMNOJaBJmKnDYth2N1UEwSiVHIQh7H05g2G2GQwx0B46CeNys341NeRw-4bDsRxnDccF1E0VAPCmGZvV1fkURCcJImErFvmlZkZgDQLgzzGCAkFYVRTXe0ctldgFRg5KkTVIstRwqcAnDXzI1eHjNLHIKUIJLTx07GDUrRDLMUSQxsuhFldykbre16wqJAUpFCxLVblRY0LAI4riiwWviUxEQTxpEhIxIk1BpNQOTfHLA1lL29SeyO-sdL0wy6GMnDVLM5jQEWIA)